# How to remove, retract, uninstall ActivityApplication with or without powershell

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, sharepoint-2010, mysite

I have been developing a solution which has a web part and allows users to post photos and links to the newsfeeds of colleagues in SharePoint 2010's MySites, the social network with SP2010. With testing and errors and such, I now have some applications people can follow in their newsfeed settings which I would like to uninstall. Retracting and Uninstalling the application with powershell did not do the trick. Does anyone else have any ideas.

I have searched extensively but as most know, the very detailed things get drowned out by all the other stuff on SP2010 in Google. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Did you remove/disable the features too?

Comment: Yup. And now, even with a reboot, it says it is retracting a solution so cannot perform any other installs or uninstalls... EECK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/3991/a-deployment-or-retraction-is-already-under-way-for-the-solu.aspx

Run "cmd"

```
cd C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\BIN
stsadm.exe -o enumdeployments
```

Get job ID

```
stsadm.exe -o canceldeployment -id "GUID jobId"
```